# How to enable static links for D3 charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, vue.js

This is on D3 v5.

Say I have the below code to display the chart:

```js
// temporary workaround
function d3json(file){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    resolve(`Show chart for "${file}" here`);
  })
}

function showChart(file){
  d3json(file).then(function(data){
    d3.select(".chart")
      .append("svg")
        .append("text")
          .attr("x", 10)
          .attr("y", 20)
          .text(data)
    ;
  })
}

d3.select("#examples")
  .on("change", function(d,i){
    d3.selectAll(".chart > *").remove();
    let selected = d3.select('#examples').property('value');
    if(selected){
      showChart(selected);
    }
  });
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<title>How to enable static links</title>

<label for="examples">Preset examples
  <select id="examples" name="examples">
    <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
    <option value="India">India</option>
  </select>
</label>

<div class="chart"></div>
```

While the charting inside the setup works very well, how can I add support for external static links? i.e. being able to show the USA chart with the link `http://mydomain/USA`? I presume this will need some kind of router setup, and I'm okay to use either a stand-alone router or something already provided by say vuejs.

Thanks!

Comment: can you explain what do you mean with "support for external links" ?

Comment: For e.g. the ability to show the USA chart with the link `http://mydomain/USA` or the India chart with `http://mydomain/India` i.e. these are now external links which I can embed in other pages with the `<a>` anchor

Comment: BTW, the components of the link are not important, as long as a link can be used. For e.g. the link could also be `http://mydomain/chart=USA` if that's going to make it any easy.

Comment: Oh i geht it you can use  vue router  and pass params ./:parameter  and evaluate those in components. I sugest to read https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#dynamic-route-matching

Comment: Thank you! I've done a fair amount of development in d3, but have zero idea of any of these front end frameworks. I did look into vue routers (both [this](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/routing.html) and [this](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html)) before posting the question, but a lot of it went over my head :-) If someone can show some boilerplate code (may be using my example above) so I can get started, that would be of great help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess all I needed was a simple client side router. Found one in [director](https://github.com/flatiron/director). With this, all I needed to do is define the route at the start of my script, using the following lines.

```
var routes = {
  '/chart/:chartID': showChart
}

var router = Router(routes);
router.init();
```

Now I can access the individual chart as `http://mydomain#/chart/USA`

The perfect non-intrusive way to making D3 charts accessible by direct links!

**EDIT**: director doesn't seem to be [maintained anymore](https://github.com/flatiron/director/issues/345). I now use [Navigo](https://github.com/krasimir/navigo).